# Android Studio: inputType personalizado

Tags: android, android-studio

En una actividad tengo varios `EditText` en los que se escribirán direcciones IP en cada uno.

He buscado un `inputType` que me permita escribir números pero con el formato `nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn`, pero no he visto ninguno.

Con el `inputType` `number` me permite escribir números, pero únicamente permite poner un `.`.

Con el `inputType` `text` si permite escribir la IP pero se muestra el teclado estándar con todas las letras, y yo quiero únicamente el teclado numérico.

¿Se puede crear un `inputType` personalizado.?

Gracias por la ayuda y saludos.

Answer (score 0):

una forma es agregar esta propiedad en el xml del EditText:

```
 android:digits="0123456789."
```